# Получить ширину всех элементов списка и сложить их

Tags: javascript

Необходимо получить ширину всех элементов списка `li` с классом `slide` и сложить их. Элементы списка добавляются динамически с AJAX.

Вот часть кода:

```
Slideshow.prototype = {
    this.slide = this.el.querySelector('.slide'); this.slideWidth();
}
slideWidth: function(){
    this.slide.offsetWidth;
}
```

Comment: Если что слайдер не так делается, а так .width() в цикле по селектору li

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, как именно не делается слайдер?

Comment: что делает приведенная часть кода, и чем она вас не устраивает?

Comment: @Qwertiy не думаю что туториал по созданию слайдера подойдёт в формат вопроса

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, я не спрашиваю, как сделать слайдер, я спрашиваю, что по твоему мнению не так в коде вопроса, раз ты говоришь, что надо делать не так. Я вообще не вижу там достаточного кода, чтобы оценить слайдер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделала так

```
Slideshow.prototype = {
    init: function() {          
        this.slide = this.el.querySelector('.slide');
this.slideWidth();},

slideWidth: function(){
        var slide_width = 0;
    slide_width += $(this.slide).width();
    console.log(slide_width);
    }
```

только не знаю как получать ширину динамически создаваемых элементов списка

Answer (score 2):

Как то так http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/gPMLRZ

Вот на js без jquery http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/adZBVy

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var summ=0;
      $('li').each(function(){
       summ += 1*$(this).width();
      });
      alert(summ);
    });
```

Comment: забыли упомянуть, что используете jQuery или подобную библиотеку, в вопросе - никаких библиотек не используется

Comment: Думаю не составит труда тоже самое переписать на js

Comment: такое решение не подойдет, ширина li всегда разная и не известна заранее

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, не понятно, почему не подойдёт. Вроде должен.

Comment: в вашем коде `li{
  width:100px;
}`

а у меня ширина всегда разная будет

Comment: @MarinaVoronova думаю не нужно объяснять что это всё равно

Answer (score 1):

На чистом js это делается с помощью свойства `offsetWidth`:

```
Slideshow.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    this.slides = this.el.querySelector('.slide');
    this.logSlidesWidth();
  },

  logSlidesWidth: function() {
    var slides_width = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
      slides_width += this.slides[i].offsetWidth;
    }
    console.log(slides_width);
  }
}
```

При выполнении данного кода будет выводиться сумма ширин всех элементов с классом `.slide`, которые в данный момент находятся в `DOM`е внутри элемента `this.el`.